# How can I query row data as columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I'm sure I'm missing something here.

I have a dataset like this:

```
FK    RowNumber    Value    Type    Status
1     1            aaaaa    A       New
1     2            bbbbb    B       Good
1     3            ccccc    A       Bad
1     4            ddddd    C       Good
1     5            eeeee    B       Good
2     1            fffff    C       Bad
2     2            ggggg    A       New
2     3            hhhhh    C       Bad
3     1            iiiii    A       Good
3     2            jjjjj    A       Good
```

I'd like to query the top 3 results and Pivot them as columns, so the end result set looks like this:

```
FK    Value1    Type1    Status1    Value2    Type2    Status2    Value3    Type3    Status3
1     aaaaa     A        New        bbbbb     B        Good       ccccc     A        Bad
2     fffff     C        Bad        ggggg     A        New        hhhhh     C        Bad
3     iiiii     A        Good       jjjjj     A        Good
```

How can I accomplish this in SQL Server 2005?

I have been attempting this using [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.105%29.aspx), but I am still very unfamiliar with that keyword and cannot get it to work the way I want.

```
SELECT * --Id, [1], [2], [3]
FROM
(
    SELECT Id, Value, Type, Status
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER Status, Type) as [RowNumber]
    FROM MyTable
) as T
PIVOT
(
    -- I know this section doesn't work. I'm still trying to figure out PIVOT
    MAX(T.Value) FOR RowNumber IN ([1], [2], [3]),
    MAX(T.Type) FOR RowNumber IN ([1], [2], [3]),
    MAX(T.Status) FOR RowNumber IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS PivotTable;
```

My actual data set is a bit more complex than this, and I need the top 10 records, not the top 3, so I don't want to simply do `CASE WHEN RowNumber = X THEN...` for each one.

**Update**

I tested all the answers below, and found most of them seem about the same with no apparent performance difference in smaller data sets (around 3k records), however there was a slight difference when running the queries against larger data sets.

Here are the results of my tests using 80,000 records and querying for 5 columns in the top 10 rows, so my end result set was 50 columns + the `Id` column. I'd suggest you test them on your own to decide which one works best for you and your environment.

- [bluefoot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12221580/302677) of unpivoting and re-pivoting the data averaged the fastest at about 12 seconds. I also liked this answer because I found it easiest to read and maintain.
- [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12221510/302677) and [koderoid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12221623/302677) both suggest using a `MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber = X THEN ...)`, and was close behind averaging at around 13 seconds.
- [Rodney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12221475/302677) of using multiple `PIVOT` statements averaged around 16 seconds, although it might be faster with fewer PIVOT statements (my tests had 5).
- And the first half of [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12221510/302677) that suggested using a CTE and `OUTER APPLY` was the slowest. I don't know how long it would take to run because I cancelled it after 2 minutes, and that was with around 3k records, 3 rows, and 3 columns instead of 80k records, 10 rows, and 5 columns.

Comment: What happened to the row with `ddddd` and `eeeee`?

Comment: @njk They're not included in the final result set since I'm only interested in getting the top X records (in my example I'm using 3, but in my actual query I need the top 10 records)

Comment: What is the criteria to select "top 10"?

Comment: @njk The final result set needs 10 rows of data. The first data set is actually obtained using the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function, and can easily be sorted and filtered to get the top 10 records. I'm more concerned about getting the 2nd result set, which queries the row data for each column

Comment: I take it Id in the second set is basically RowNumber from the first set and nothing to do with Id in the first set?  Id from the first set becomes the indexer on the array in the second set?  This should be a pretty standard PIVOT.  Can you give the code you've tried with PIVOT?

Comment: @CadeRoux The `Id` in both sets is a ForeignKey to another table, and is not the same as the RowNumber in the 2nd set. I updated my question with the query I'm currently testing with.

Comment: @Rachel But it's two completely different FKs right?

Comment: @CadeRoux No, it's the same FK. I know I could write the query with a ton of `CASE WHEN RowNumber = X THEN Value...` statements, but I thought there'd be an easy solution that did not involve 50 case statements (I need 5 columns from the top 10 rows, so 50 columns in my result set + the Id column)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do an `UNPIVOT` and then a `PIVOT` of the data. this can be done either statically or dynamically:

Static Version:

```
select *
from
(
  select fk, col + cast(rownumber as varchar(1)) new_col,
    val
  from 
  (
    select fk, rownumber, value, cast(type as varchar(10)) type,
      status
    from yourtable
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
    val
    for col in (value, type, status)
  ) u
) x1
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for new_col in
    ([value1], [type1], [status1], 
     [value2], [type2], [status2],
    [value3], [type3])
) p
```

see [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3290f/6)

Dynamic Version,  this will get the list of columns to `unpivot` and then to `pivot` at run-time:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
               C.name not in ('fk', 'rownumber')
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
                      + quotename(c.name 
                         + cast(t.rownumber as varchar(10)))
                    from yourtable t
                     cross apply 
                      sys.columns as C
                   where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
                         C.name not in ('fk', 'rownumber')
                   group by c.name, t.rownumber
                   order by t.rownumber
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
        select fk, col + cast(rownumber as varchar(10)) new_col,
          val
        from 
        (
          select fk, rownumber, value, cast(type as varchar(10)) type,
            status
          from yourtable
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for new_col in
          ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3290f/33)

Both will generate the same results, however the dynamic is great if you do not know the number of columns ahead of time.

The Dynamic version is working under the assumption that the rownumber is already a part of the dataset.

Comment: +1 but `VARCHAR(1)` will break the value `10`. Also I'm getting an error about type conflicts (the demo you have has rownumber as a column in the table; it needs to be manufactured at runtime I think). So I'm having a hard time testing outside of your demo.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I used `varchar(1)` as an example since there were only 1-5 row numbers present, it would need to be extended for longer values. I based my demo off the data provided, if the `rownumber` is not present then yes it would need to be evaluated prior to use. I based it off the dataset presented showing it is possible via an `unpivot` and then `pivot`.

Comment: Here and on the heap she's explained she needs 10 sets (she just used 3 in the sample).

Comment: ok, I am trying to get a dynamic version working as well. I just figured I would post a static version immediately. :)

Comment: +1 - nice. I was wondering how come you hadn't answered yet ;-)

Comment: Oh, nice preparation then. Congrats!

Comment: @AaronBertrand added dynamic version to get all rows at run-time

Comment: I modified the query to work with my actual data set, and although the `UNPIVOT` appears to work Ok, the final pivoted query returns all `NULL` values even though there is no null values in the unpivoted data set. Still trying to figure out why that is now

Comment: @Rachel if you are getting `NULL` values, then you can implement an `IsNull()` around each column, this can even be added to the dynamic version of the query

Comment: @bluefeet I don't have any `NULL` values in the data though, which is confusing me. I can remove the last pivot from the static query and add `where new_col is null or val is null` and it returns no records.

Comment: @Rachel it is hard to say without seeing the full sample of data.  Can you create a sqlfiddle with a full sample?

Comment: @bluefeet I'll try... a lot of the data I'm working with is private so I can't disclose the exact values. Do you know if there's a setting for SQL Fiddle for SQL 2005? I'm curious to know if that makes a difference as I can't see any difference between my data and yours

Comment: @Rachel I understand that.  I will still try to play with what I have

Comment: @bluefeet I entered some actual data, complete with null values and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, but your fiddle still works while my SQL query does not. The only differences I can think of is the table is actually a subquery containing 5 table joins, and I am running a different version of SQL server. I need to get going, but I hope to pick this back up on Tuesday. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out and I'll let you know if I figure out what my problem is :)

Comment: @Rachel ok, even if you could scrub a larger data set then I could get a better idea of the issue.

Comment: @bluefeet Actually I figured it out just as I was about to leave :) I was using my own column names so my unpivot was `val for col in (MyValueColumn, MyTypeColumn, MyStatusColumn)`, but I forgot to change the `PIVOT` to pivot using the new column names. Once I replaced my column names with `value`, `type`, and `status`, it works. I'm sorry for distracting you from your wedding, and congratulations on it! :)

Comment: @Rachel glad you figured it out.

Comment: Thanks @bluefoot, this actually turned out to perform the best for my situation and environment. I updated my question with test results if you're interested :)

Comment: @Rachel glad you were able to get this to work for your situation. :)

Answer (score 7):

You can try to do the pivot in three separate pivot statements. Please give this a try:

```
SELECT Id
    ,MAX(S1) [Status 1]
    ,MAX(T1) [Type1]
    ,MAX(V1) [Value1]
    --, Add other columns
FROM
(
    SELECT Id, Value , Type, Status
    , 'S' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Status, Type) AS VARCHAR(10)) [Status_RowNumber]
    , 'T' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Status, Type) AS VARCHAR(10)) [Type_RowNumber]
    , 'V' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Status, Type) AS VARCHAR(10)) [Value_RowNumber]
    FROM MyTable
) as T
PIVOT
(   
    MAX(Status) FOR Status_RowNumber IN ([S1], [S2], [S3],[S4],[S5],[S6],[S7],[S8],[S9],[S10])
)AS StatusPivot
PIVOT(
    MAX(Type) FOR Type_RowNumber IN ([T1], [T2], [T3],[T4],[T5],[T6],[T7],[T8],[T9],[T10])
)AS Type_Pivot
PIVOT(
    MAX(Value) FOR Value_RowNumber IN ([V1], [V2], [V3],[V4],[V5],[V6],[V7],[V8],[V9],[V10])
)AS Value_Pivot
GROUP BY Id
```

I don't know the full scope of the criteria for selecting the top ten records, but this produces and output that may get you closer to your answer.

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15be1/1)

Comment: +1, very clever. But please don't use `VARCHAR` without length. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: I've updated my statement to include the varchar length. That was a very helpful article.

Comment: You could make it even tidier by using a second subquery to derive the row_number. Should only be evaluated once in either case, but it will look prettier. :-)

Comment: This actually works way better than I thought it would! I used it to get 4 columns of the top 10 records for about 4000 FK records, and there was no noticeable delay in running the query. I'd still like to try running it against a larger result set and try out some of the other answers posted here to see if there's any performance difference, but I'm very happy to actually have a solution :) (PS @AaronBertrand What do you mean about a second subquery? My query could definitely use any prettifying it can get)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ahhhh that makes sense now, thank you. I need to get going, but I plan on picking this back up Tuesday and will let you know how it goes. Thank you :)

Comment: @Rachel I don't see anything version-specific, so I really doubt 2005 is giving you different results because of the code, it is because of the data.

Comment: Although I like this solution, it turned out that unpivoting/pivoting the data like [bluefoot suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12221580/302677) was faster for my specific situation. I updated my question with my test results if you're interested :)

Answer (score 2):

Rodney's muli-pivot is clever, that's for sure. Here are two other alternatives that are of course less appealing when you get into the 10X vs. 3X area.

```
;WITH a AS
(
    SELECT Id, Value, Type, Status, 
      n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Status], [Type])
    FROM dbo.MyTable
)
SELECT a.Id, 
 Value1 = a.Value, Type1 = a.[Type], Status1 = a.[Status],
 Value2 = b.Value, Type2 = b.[Type], Status2 = b.[Status],
 Value3 = c.Value, Type3 = c.[Type], Status3 = c.[Status]
FROM a
OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM a AS T2 WHERE n = a.n + 1 AND id = a.id) AS b
OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM a AS T2 WHERE n = b.n + 1 AND id = b.id) AS c
WHERE a.n = 1
ORDER BY a.Id;
```

-- or --

```
;WITH a AS
(
    SELECT Id, Value, [Type], [Status], 
      n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Status], [Type])
    FROM dbo.MyTable
)
SELECT Id,
  Value1  = MAX(CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN Value    END),
  Type1   = MAX(CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN [Type]   END),
  Status1 = MAX(CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN [Status] END),
  Value2  = MAX(CASE WHEN n = 2 THEN Value    END),
  Type2   = MAX(CASE WHEN n = 2 THEN [Type]   END),
  Status2 = MAX(CASE WHEN n = 2 THEN [Status] END),
  Value3  = MAX(CASE WHEN n = 3 THEN Value    END),
  Type3   = MAX(CASE WHEN n = 3 THEN [Type]   END),
  Status3 = MAX(CASE WHEN n = 3 THEN [Status] END)
FROM a
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY a.Id;
```

Comment: In your first scenario, do you know if the CTE gets evaluated for each join? Meaning if I create 10 joins to get the top 10 records, will the CTE get evaluated 10 times?

Comment: @Rachel impossible to know without testing, sorry. Too many variables can dictate whether a CTE will be evaluated more than once.

Comment: The first query with the CTE is definitely not going to work for me because of performance, but the second one has a decent run time. I updated my question with the results of my tests if you're interested :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you, though it's not elegant.

```
select aa.FK_Id
    , isnull(max(aa.Value1), '') as Value1
    , isnull(max(aa.Type1), '') as Type1
    , isnull(max(aa.Status1), '') as Status1
    , isnull(max(aa.Value2), '') as Value2
    , isnull(max(aa.Type2), '') as Type2
    , isnull(max(aa.Status2), '') as Status2
    , isnull(max(aa.Value3), '') as Value3
    , isnull(max(aa.Type3), '') as Type3
    , isnull(max(aa.Status3), '') as Status3
from
(       
    select FK_Id
            , case when RowNumber = 1 then Value else null end as Value1
            , case when RowNumber = 1 then [Type] else null end as Type1
            , case when RowNumber = 1 then [Status] else null end as Status1
            , case when RowNumber = 2 then Value else null end as Value2
            , case when RowNumber = 2 then [Type] else null end as Type2
            , case when RowNumber = 2 then [Status] else null end as Status2
            , case when RowNumber = 3 then Value else null end as Value3
            , case when RowNumber = 3 then [Type] else null end as Type3
            , case when RowNumber = 3 then [Status] else null end as Status3
    from Table1
) aa
group by aa.FK_Id
```

Comment: Yeah this was my backup plan. I need to select 5 columns from the top 10 records though, which results in 50 case statements

Comment: When you have both solutions, please keep us posted for the performance. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
declare @rowCount int 
set @rowCount = 10

declare @isNullClause varchar(4024)
set @isnullClause = ''
declare @caseClause varchar(4024)
set @caseClause = ''

declare @i int 
set @i = 1

while(@i <= @rowCount) begin 
    set @isnullClause = @isNullClause + 
                        ' , max(aa.Value' + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) + ') as Value'    + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) +
                        ' , max(aa.Type' + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) + ') as Type'  + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) +
                        ' , max(aa.Status' + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) + ') as Status'  + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) + ' '; 
    set @caseClause = @caseClause + 
        ' , case when RowNumber = ' + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) + ' then Value else null end as Value' + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) +
        ' , case when RowNumber = ' + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) + ' then Type else null end as Type' + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) +
        ' , case when RowNumber = ' + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) + ' then Status else null end as Status' + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) + ' '


    set @i = @i + 1; 
end

declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
set @sql = 'select aa.FK_Id ' + @isnullClause + ' from ( select FK_Id ' 
            + @caseClause + '  from Table1) aa group by aa.FK_Id '

exec SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
```

Comment: +1 for providing a dynamic way of building the CASE WHEN version of the query :)