# SQL turning values returned in 11 rows into 89 total columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need some help with turning rows of data into columns.

Each of my rows consists of 8 columns, all of which I would like to be included in the final column list.

Normally, I would write a select statement like the one below to return all the pricing rows (about 11) that pertain to a particular `ProductID`

```
SELECT  
    ProductID,
    PricingID, 
    COSBeginQty ,
    COSCOLCode,
    COSTrade,
    COSTypeOfPrice,
    COSIsActive, 
    COSPrice,
    COSPriceTAG,
    RowIndex
FROM 
    Pricing
Where 
    ProductID = XXXXX
```

Each of my returned rows has about What I would like is to display all the returned values:

```
ProductID, 
CosBeginQty1 COSBeginQty1  COSCOLCode1 COSTrade1 COSTypeOfPrice1 COSIsActive1 COSPrice1 COSPriceTAG1  
CosBeginQty2 COSBeginQty2  COSCOLCode2 COSTrade2 COSTypeOfPrice2 COSIsActive2 COSPrice2 COSPriceTAG2  
CosBeginQty3, COSBeginQty3  COSCOLCode3 COSTrade3 COSTypeOfPrice3 COSIsActive3 COSPrice3 COSPriceTAG3   . . . .
```

. . .(counting the values I need from all the 11 rows, there 89 total) columns

Here is a look at the script fro my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pricing](
    [ProductID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PricingID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [COSBeginQty] [int] NULL,
    [COSCOLCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [COSTrade] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [COSTypeOfPrice] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [COSIsActive] [bit] NULL,
    [COSPrice] [decimal](12, 3) NULL,
    [COSPriceTAG] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [RowIndex] [int] NULL,
    [COSCreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [COSLastModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Pricing] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pricing] ([ProductID], [PricingID], [COSBeginQty], [COSCOLCode], [COSTrade], [COSTypeOfPrice], [COSIsActive], [COSPrice], [COSPriceTAG], [RowIndex], [COSCreateDate], [COSLastModifiedDate]) VALUES (N'99533f6e-218f-48ef-bf01-03ea7808f9b1', N'5d8de11a-2399-4c68-87cd-4969827bed27', 7, N'MAN', N'T1', N'B         ', 1, CAST(23.400 AS Decimal(12, 3)), N'bf1d79bf-a60d-4603-8c2d-04492e9e1575', 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pricing] ([ProductID], [PricingID], [COSBeginQty], [COSCOLCode], [COSTrade], [COSTypeOfPrice], [COSIsActive], [COSPrice], [COSPriceTAG], [RowIndex], [COSCreateDate], [COSLastModifiedDate]) VALUES (N'94d67d13-e4e6-4360-9b7a-1cef7d997297', N'5ba0a6e9-53ed-4b9c-a9eb-2b09c41eb56c', 2, N'MAN', N'T2', N'A         ', 1, CAST(3456.234 AS Decimal(12, 3)), N'6ce7d421-e49a-469f-ae4c-a8bbb2f432fc', 3, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pricing] ([ProductID], [PricingID], [COSBeginQty], [COSCOLCode], [COSTrade], [COSTypeOfPrice], [COSIsActive], [COSPrice], [COSPriceTAG], [RowIndex], [COSCreateDate], [COSLastModifiedDate]) VALUES (N'e2216b52-66a9-4c29-a8ec-83c6ae03cd18', N'a8c27e9a-120c-47f2-bdd9-3e9e934ca237', 12, N'TEM', N'T1', N'B         ', 1, CAST(7234.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)), N'555c0f25-6af9-4114-8f11-096f0e5c7bcd', 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Pricing] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Pricing_ProductID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ProductID]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Pricing] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Pricing_PricingID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [PricingID]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Pricing] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Pricing_COSPriceTAG]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [COSPriceTAG]
GO
```

**THE SOLUTION TO THE PROBLEM IS AS BELOW THANKS TO BLUEFEET**

```
select *, row_number() over(partition by ProductID order by ProductID) rn
from dbo.pricing;

DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('Pricing') and
               C.name LIKE '%COS%'
               and C.name Not in ('COSCreateDate', 'COSLastModifiedDate')
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
                      + quotename(c.name 
                         + cast(t.rn as varchar(10)))
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by productid 
                                               order by productid) rn
                      from Pricing
                    ) t
                     cross apply 
                      sys.columns as C
                   where C.object_id = object_id('Pricing') and
                         C.name LIKE '%COS%'
                     and C.name Not in ('COSCreateDate', 'COSLastModifiedDate')
                   group by c.name, t.rn
                   order by t.rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
        select ProductID,
            col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col,
            val
        from 
        (
          select ProductID,
              PricingID, 
              cast(COSBeginQty as varchar(50)) COSBeginQty,
              cast(COSCOLCode as varchar(50)) COSCOLCode,
              cast(COSTrade as varchar(50)) COSTrade,
              cast(COSTypeOfPrice as varchar(50)) COSTypeOfPrice,
              cast(COSIsActive as varchar(50)) COSIsActive, 
              cast(COSPrice as varchar(50)) COSPrice,
              cast(COSPriceTAG as varchar(50)) COSPriceTAG,
              RowIndex,
              row_number() over(partition by productid 
                                               order by productid) rn
          from Pricing
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for new_col in
          ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

Comment: I am not sure how pivot would work in this case given I have no predefined range or values for the values to expect in each of the columns of my original select statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I query row data as columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221037/how-can-i-query-row-data-as-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your full table structure or sample data it looks like you can do something like this, using dynamic SQL. This uses both `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` to get the results:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

The first piece `@colsUnpivot` which gets the list of the columns that you need to `UNPIVOT` to then re-pivot.  You need to `UNPIVOT` because you want your result to include multiple versions of each of these columns - `CosBeginQty1, CosBeginQty2, CosBeginQty3`

```
select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('Pricing') and
               C.name LIKE '%COS%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

The code to get the `@colsPivot` is getting the final columns.  These values (`CosBeginQty1, CosBeginQty2, CosBeginQty3`) are retrieved by applying the `row_number` to each of the rows in the table.

```
select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
                      + quotename(c.name 
                         + cast(t.rn as varchar(10)))
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by productid 
                                               order by productid) rn
                      from Pricing
                    ) t
                     cross apply 
                      sys.columns as C
                   where C.object_id = object_id('Pricing') and
                         C.name LIKE '%COS%'
                   group by c.name, t.rn
                   order by t.rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

This final part generates the dynamic sql statement to execute.  It uses both the `@colsUnpivot` and `@colsPivot` values to form the final sql statement to query.

```
set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
        select ProductID, PricingID, RowIndex,
            col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col,
            val
        from 
        (
          select ProductID,
              PricingID, 
              COSBeginQty,
              COSCOLCode,
              COSTrade,
              COSTypeOfPrice,
              COSIsActive, 
              COSPrice,
              COSPriceTAG,
              RowIndex,
              row_number() over(partition by productid 
                                               order by productid) rn
          from Pricing
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for new_col in
          ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

This solution associates a `row_number()` to each of the values, then `UNPIVOT`s the columns and finally `PIVOT`s them with the `row_number()` added to each column name.

A `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` can be performed statically but since you will have a unknown number of values to `PIVOT` then you should use a dynamic version. If you were using a static version then it would look something like this:

```
select *
from
(
   select ProductID, PricingID, RowIndex,
      col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col,
      val
   from 
   (
     select ProductID,
         PricingID, 
         COSBeginQty,
         COSCOLCode,
         COSTrade,
         COSTypeOfPrice,
         COSIsActive, 
         COSPrice,
         COSPriceTAG,
         RowIndex,
         row_number() over(partition by productid 
                                               order by productid) rn
     from Pricing
   ) x
   unpivot
   (
      val
      for col in (COSBeginQty, COSCOLCode, COSTrade, COSTypeOfPrice
                 COSIsActive, COSPrice, COSPriceTAG)
   ) u
) x1
pivot
(
   max(val)
   for new_col in ([COSBeginQty1], [COSCOLCode1], [COSTrade1], [COSTypeOfPrice1],
                   [COSIsActive1], [COSPrice1], [COSPriceTAG1],
                  [COSBeginQty2], [COSCOLCode2], [COSTrade2], [COSTypeOfPrice2],
                   [COSIsActive2], [COSPrice2], [COSPriceTAG2])
) p
```

Edit #2, applying your sample data, the script would look like this:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('Pricing') and
               C.name LIKE '%COS%'
               and C.name Not in ('COSCreateDate', 'COSLastModifiedDate')
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
                      + quotename(c.name 
                         + cast(t.rn as varchar(10)))
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by productid 
                                               order by productid) rn
                      from Pricing
                    ) t
                     cross apply 
                      sys.columns as C
                   where C.object_id = object_id('Pricing') and
                         C.name LIKE '%COS%'
                     and C.name Not in ('COSCreateDate', 'COSLastModifiedDate')
                   group by c.name, t.rn
                   order by t.rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
        select ProductID, PricingID, RowIndex,
            col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col,
            val
        from 
        (
          select ProductID,
              PricingID, 
              cast(COSBeginQty as varchar(50)) COSBeginQty,
              cast(COSCOLCode as varchar(50)) COSCOLCode,
              cast(COSTrade as varchar(50)) COSTrade,
              cast(COSTypeOfPrice as varchar(50)) COSTypeOfPrice,
              cast(COSIsActive as varchar(50)) COSIsActive, 
              cast(COSPrice as varchar(50)) COSPrice,
              cast(COSPriceTAG as varchar(50)) COSPriceTAG,
              RowIndex,
              row_number() over(partition by productid 
                                               order by productid) rn
          from Pricing
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for new_col in
          ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fc2d/8)

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing in this piece ---   select ProductID, PricingID, RowIndex
      col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col,
      val

Comment: @Kobojunkie I missed a comma when I wrote it, please see my edit.  It would be very helpful if you posted some sample data or created a {SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).  At this point, I am guessing at the data in your columns.

Comment: I get a "The type of column "COSBeginQty" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list." Any Idea how I can fix this problem please?

Comment: You will have to cast all values to be the same data type. You will perform this cast in the select before the unpivot.

Comment: Are you available for chat on this please?

Comment: Not at this point, I am on a mobile. My suggestion is to post some sample data for me to look at or create a sqlfiddle.com. It is difficult to debug without seeing any data.

Comment: I added the script for the table with data as well to the Original post then.

Comment: Thank you for the SQLFiddle sample. I ran the code you have on there and it does not seem to do what I want it to. What I want is to have  COSBEGINQTY1 COSCOLCODE1 COSISACTIVE1 COSPRICE1 COSPRICETAG1 COSTRADE1 COSTYPEOFPRICE1 COSBEGINQTY2 COSCOLCODE2 COSISACTIVE2 COSPRICE2 COSPRICETAG2 COSTRADE2 COSTYPEOFPRICE2  COSBEGINQTY3 COSCOLCODE3 COSISACTIVE3 COSPRICE3 COSPRICETAG3 COSTRADE3 COSTYPEOFPRICE3 and only one row of data returned

Comment: You have 3 different `ProductId`s, so why would you want them in the same row?

Comment: one other question. How would I extend the code to product all 11 column sets(fill in null values where appropriate) for all rows in my returned table?

Comment: @Kobojunkie you would have to expand the query by adding the new columns to the `UNPIVOT`

Comment: I 'expanded' the code to generate 11 rows per product record but I got stuck with trimming it down to generating only records for products with records in the pricing table. I would appreciate any input you may have to this please. The code is at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f227/2

Comment: I have one more question please. Does this sample solution work when the child table is replaced with a temp table? I ask because I decided to switch tables and trying to understand why I am not getting same results

Comment: @Kobojunkie you would have to alter the code to use a #temp table. If the tables do not have the same structure/columns then I don't think it would work.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use dynamic sql, then this might do for you.

```
DECLARE @OUTPUT NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @OUTPUT = "XXXXX"
SELECT @OUTPUT = @OUTPUT + "," + PricingID + COSBeginQty + COSCOLCode + COSTrade + COSTypeOfPrice + COSIsActive + COSPrice + COSPriceTAG + RowIndex
FROM Pricing
Where ProductID = XXXXX
```