# SQL: Putting an individuals distinct diagnosis into one horizontal row

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 for a mental health organization.

I have a table that lists all of out clients and their diagnoses, but each diagnoses that a client has is in a new row.  I want them all to be in a single row listed out horizontally with the date for each diagnosis.  Some people have just one diagnosis, some have 20, some have none.

Here's an example of how my data sort of looks now (only with a lot few clients, we have thousands):
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BiKz.png]

And Here's the format I'd like it to end up:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r37Wo.png]

Any solutions you could offer or hints in the right direction would be great, thanks!

Comment: Are you showing query results or table structure?

Comment: Why do you need the results in that format? I wonder if there might be a higher up/simpler solution.

Comment: I'm looking to put it in an easier format and then put it into a table so that I can query that table easier to say get a list of all clients with diabetes.  Though if there's an easier way of doing that I'd be open to it.

Comment: oh and it's query results not a table structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL turning values returned in 11 rows into 89 total columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553897/sql-turning-values-returned-in-11-rows-into-89-total-columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the result, I would first unpivot and then pivot your data.  The *unpivot* will take your date and diagnosis columns and convert them into rows. Once the data is in rows, then you can apply the pivot.

If you have a known number of values, then you can hard-code your query similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
  select person, [case#], age,
    col+'_'+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
    value
  from
  (
    select person, 
      [case#],
      age,
      diagnosis,
      convert(varchar(10), diagnosisdate, 101) diagnosisDate,
      row_number() over(partition by person, [case#]
                        order by DiagnosisDate) rn
    from yourtable
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    values ('diagnosis', diagnosis), ('diagnosisDate', diagnosisDate)
  ) c (col, value)
) t
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (diagnosis_1, diagnosisDate_1,
              diagnosis_2, diagnosisDate_2,
              diagnosis_3, diagnosisDate_3,
              diagnosis_4, diagnosisDate_4)

) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c87f0/7).

I am going to assume that you will have an unknown number of diagnosis values for each case. If that is the case, then you will need to use dynamic sql to generate the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(col+'_'+cast(rn as varchar(10))) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by person, [case#]
                                                order by DiagnosisDate) rn
                      from yourtable
                    ) t
                    cross join 
                    (
                      select 'Diagnosis' col union all 
                      select 'DiagnosisDate'
                    ) c
                    group by col, rn
                    order by rn, col
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT person, 
                    [case#],
                    age,' + @cols + '  
             from
             (
                select person, [case#], age,
                  col+''_''+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
                  value
                from
                (
                  select person, 
                    [case#],
                    age,
                    diagnosis,
                    convert(varchar(10), diagnosisdate, 101) diagnosisDate,
                    row_number() over(partition by person, [case#]
                                      order by DiagnosisDate) rn
                  from yourtable
                ) d
                cross apply
                (
                  values (''diagnosis'', diagnosis), (''diagnosisDate'', diagnosisDate)
                ) c (col, value)
            ) t
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c87f0/14). Both queries give the result:

```
| PERSON |  CASE# | AGE |   DIAGNOSIS_1 | DIAGNOSISDATE_1 |      DIAGNOSIS_2 | DIAGNOSISDATE_2 |        DIAGNOSIS_3 | DIAGNOSISDATE_3 |  DIAGNOSIS_4 | DIAGNOSISDATE_4 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   John |  13784 |  56 |    Depression |      03/13/2012 |     Brain Injury |      03/14/2012 | Spinal Cord Injury |      03/15/2012 | Hypertension |      03/16/2012 |
|   Kate |   2643 |  37 |       Bipolar |      03/11/2012 |     Hypertension |      03/12/2012 |             (null) |          (null) |       (null) |          (null) |
|  Kevin | 500934 |  25 | Down Syndrome |      03/18/2012 | Clinical Obesity |      03/19/2012 |             (null) |          (null) |       (null) |          (null) |
|   Pete | 803342 |  34 |  Schizophenia |      03/17/2012 |           (null) |          (null) |             (null) |          (null) |       (null) |          (null) |
```

Answer (score 1):

For this type of pivoting, I think the aggregate/group method is feasible:

```
select d.case, d.person,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then diagnosis end) as d1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then diagnosisdate end) as d1date,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then diagnosis end) as d2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then diagnosisdate end) as d2date,
       . . . -- and so on, for as many groups that you want
from (select d.*, row_number() over (partition by case order by diagnosisdate) as seqnum
      from diagnoses d
     ) d
group by d.case, d.person
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with sensitive medical information, identifyiable information (name age etc) shouldn't be stored in the same table as the medical information. Also, if you extract out the person info into its own table and a Diagnosis table that has the personID foreign key you can establish the 1 to many relationship you want.

Comment: How does that have any bearing on the question?

Comment: @MaxVernon `hints in the right direction`, and I think @actkatiemacias is trying to point out that he should normalize his table for better usage

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use Dynamic SQL, the PIVOT operator will not work here. I assume that patients can come in on any date. The PIVOT operator works with a finite and predefined number of columns. Your options are to use Dynamic SQL to create the PIVOT table, or to use Excel or a reporting tool like SSRS to do a Pivot report.

I think the Dynamic SQL option would not be practical here, since, you could end up having hundreds of columns for each of the patient visit dates.

If you want to explore the Dynamic SQL option anyway, have a look here:

https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/