# Putting an individuals distinct diagnosis into one horizontal row AND excluding a specific diagnosis

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working from the same query as explained in this question: [Diagnosis in One Horizontal Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816090/sql-putting-an-individuals-distinct-diagnosis-into-one-horizontal-row). The diagnosis data is now horizontal and I want to exclude those with active dementia (diagnosis status is indicated for each diagnosis). The max # of diagnoses per person is 50 so I have to search each of the 50 ICD9 Code fields for each of the 18 different ICD9 codes (indicating dementia). I have declared each of the 18 codes as @ICD9Code49 - @ICD9Code66, but cannot figure out how to exclude these from my data set. I have tried the following (ProblemStatus is the diagnosis status):

```
SELECT * FROM Diagnosis
WHERE
(
([ProblemStatus_1] = @ProblemStatus AND (ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code49 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code50 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code51 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code52 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code53 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code54 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code55 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code56 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code57 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code58 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code59 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code60 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code61 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code62 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code63 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code64 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code65 OR ICD9Code_1 <> @ICD9Code66))
AND ([ProblemStatus_2] = @ProblemStatus AND (ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code49 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code50 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code51 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code52 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code53 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code54 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code55 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code56 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code57 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code58 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code59 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code60 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code61 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code62 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code63 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code64 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code65 OR ICD9Code_2 <> @ICD9Code66))
AND ([ProblemStatus_3] = @ProblemStatus AND (ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code49 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code50 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code51 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code52 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code53 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code54 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code55 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code56 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code57 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code58 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code59 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code60 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code61 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code62 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code63 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code64 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code65 OR ICD9Code_3 <> @ICD9Code66))
)
```

I've tried various combinations of AND's and OR's but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great time for `NOT IN`:

```
with dementiaCodes as (
    select @ICD9Code49 as code
    union all select @ICD9Code50
    union all select @ICD9Code51
    ...
)
SELECT * FROM Diagnosis
WHERE
NOT ((ProblemStatus_1 = @ProblemStatus AND ICD9Code_1 IN (select code from dementiaCodes))
    OR (ProblemStatus_2 = @ProblemStatus AND ICD9Code_2 IN (select code from dementiaCodes))
    OR (ProblemStatus_3 = @ProblemStatus AND ICD9Code_3 IN (select code from dementiaCodes)))
```

Comment: @user2483743 I misunderstood. Sorry about that. I still think `NOT IN` is a good way, but I changed the logic to exclude if any of the 50 codes are dementia codes. I've removed the problem status from the query because I don't know what to do with it. Can you clarify the problem status portion, particularly how it should relate to the codes?

Comment: The problem status is the diagnosis status. It tells me if the diagnosis is active, in remission, inactive, etc. I only need to exclude patients with active dementia so I have to clarify this for each diagnosis.

Comment: @user2483743 I've updated the query to exclude records where there exists a diagnosis that both fits the "@ProblemStatus" and has a code that is in dementiaCodes.

Comment: The logic of the query makes sense, but I'm getting 0 results. If I comment out "NOT" it returns the 12 patients with dementia, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: @user2483743 I'm not sure why either. The query looks simple enough. Maybe the data is not as you expect it? Can you make a sql fiddle with a small example data set and schema?

Comment: I created a table variable for dementia diagnosis codes then used a nested query to filter them out.